# XJC Generating same classes

Tags: xsd, jaxb, xjc

I'm using JAXB on two different XSDs. Some of the generated classes appear to be the same. Is this unusual, and when I copy the classes over to my source package structure, should I just copy over the duplicate classes?
Or, is it possible to run xjc with a flag that says not to copy over/generate duplicate classes?

Answer (score 0):

It's the episodes feature you are after.

[This post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869547/jaxb-creating-modules-for-reuse) might help, along with [this](http://blog.geekosaurus.net/?p=62); the latter might be a bit outdated, but I've seen people asking questions on SO about issues long solved in newer versions of JAXB, so one never knows...