# How to inform xjc not to go through xs:import?

Tags: java, ant, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I want to create a java classes from the xsd using xjc ant task. Most of it works ok. I need it not to go through  and   because it already has mapping done. 
Here is xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:digitalsignature:1.0"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:dsig="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:digitalsignature:1.0"
   xmlns:xmldsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
   xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" 
   elementFormDefault="qualified"
  >
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
       schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" />
    <xs:import namespace="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" 
       schemaLocation="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2/XAdES.xsd" />
    <xs:import namespace="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" 
       schemaLocation="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1/XAdESv141.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="document-signatures">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="xmldsig:Signature" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

xjc goes through all imports and creates binding classes. But I already have those. So how to inform xjc to use already created bindings in the classpath? 
For xades implementation I'll use [xades4j](http://code.google.com/p/xades4j/) library

Thanks,

Vidmantas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use episode files to do modular schema compilation:

- [JAXB - Creating modules for reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869547/jaxb-creating-modules-for-reuse/5872659#5872659)
- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2006/09/separate_compil.html?force=741