# What is an .episode file..?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

what is a .episode file in JAXB..? Is it generated by the JAXB or is it a configuration file that we'd manipulate to avoid regeneration of the same classes by JAXB..?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Note:** I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/MOXy) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

A .episode file is generated by the XJC (XML Schema to Java) compiler.  It is a schema bindings that associates schema types with existing classes.  It is useful when you have one XML schema that is imported by other schemas as it prevents the model from being regenerated.  Below is an example:

**Product.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Product" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Product" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="product">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="id" type="string"/>
                <element name="name" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

Since multiple XML schemas import Product.xsd we can leverage episode files so that the classes corresponding to Product.xsd are only generated once.

```
xjc -d out -episode product.episode Product.xsd
```

**ProductPurchaseRequest.xsd**

Below is an example of an XML schema that imports Product.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/ProductPurchaseRequest" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/ProductPurchaseRequest"
    xmlns:prod="http://www.example.org/Product" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <import namespace="http://www.example.org/Product" schemaLocation="Product.xsd"/>
    <element name="purchase-request">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element ref="prod:product" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

When we generate classes from this XML schema we will reference the episode file we created when we generated Java classes from Product.xsd.

```
xjc -d out ProductPurchaseRequest.xsd -extension -b product.episode
```

**ProductQuoteRequest.xsd**

Below is another example of an XML schema that imports Product.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/ProductQuoteRequest" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/ProductQuoteRequest" 
    xmlns:prod="http://www.example.org/Product" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <import namespace="http://www.example.org/Product" schemaLocation="Product.xsd"/>
    <element name="quote">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element ref="prod:product"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

Again when we generate classes from this XML schema we will reference the episode file we created when we generated Java classes from Product.xsd.

```
xjc -d out ProductQuoteRequest.xsd -extension -b product.episode
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/reusing-generated-jaxb-classes.html

Comment: This does not reliably work with the `maven-jaxb2-plugin`, though you can provide the episode file, you have to provide the original schema file also. Quote from the plugin user guide: Note that JAXB still needs to access BOTH A and B schemas during the compilation. You may use catalogs to provide alternative locations of the imported schemas.

Answer (score 12):

I'll add some trivia.

- Actually, `.episode` files are just normal binding files (that's why they work with `xjc -b`).
- They can be generated with a special built-in plugin (that's what `-episode` does).
- If placed in a JAR under the `META-INF/sun-jaxb.episode` path, you can do `xjc b.xsd a.jar` - XJC will scan JARs for episode files then an use the as binding files automatically.
- All of this beauty works fine with Maven ([maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin)). However, with later version you can use binding files from JAR artifacts even without episodes.

Comment: Very good. But I cannot bind a documentation about use the JAR artifacts

Comment: @Dherik See resource entries, just use them with `bindings` instead of `schemas`: http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Resourceentries

Answer (score 1):

Just an addon to the answer, I would like to provide an input on how to avoid having .episode file generated while using maven-jaxb2-plugin

```
         `<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>schema-conversion</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/schema/myschema</schemaDirectory>
                        <bindingDirectory>src/main/schema/myschema</bindingDirectory>
                        <bindingIncludes>
                            <include>binding_info.xjb</include>
                        </bindingIncludes>
                        <generateDirectory>src/main/java/</generateDirectory>
                        <episode>false</episode>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>`
```

**`<episode>false</episode>`** will make it disappear.

Comment: This is no longer a valid configuration in version 2.5.0 of jaxb2-maven-plugin

Comment: @lukas84 `maven-jaxb2-plugin` and `jaxb2-maven-plugin` are different plugins with different options.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, they're for [modular schema creation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6843447/517815).

This implies that the files themselves can be used both as a configurator and as a generative view of a data layer for downstream processing. More context would be needed to determine which is being referred to here.