# Using maven jaxb2 plugin, modular compilation using episode and catalog throws Malformed URL error

Tags: jaxb, catalog, maven-jaxb2-plugin, malformedurlexception, jaxb-episode

My project contains A.xsd which imports schema as follows from B.xsd which is part of another project:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://com.test.schema/common/Context" schemaLocation="http://com.test.schema/common/Context/B.xsd"/>
```

I am trying to use the episode from the project which contains B.xsd so that classes related to B.xsd do not get re-generated when A.xsd is parsed. So I referred [this](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2006/09/separate_compil.html?force=741) and [this](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Episodes) to come up with the following configuration:
Here is the pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bar.foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>schema-b</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependencies>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <build>
        <plugins>
        <dependency>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <episodes>
                                <episode>
                                    <groupId>com.bar.foo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>schema-b</artifactId>
                                </episode>
                            </episodes>
                            <catalog>src/main/resources/catalog.cat</catalog>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>

                                    <fileset>
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/schemas</directory>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>A.xsd</include>
                                            <include>...</include>
                                            <include>...</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                            <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/schemas</bindingDirectory>
                            <bindingIncludes>
                                <include>*.xjb</include>
                            </bindingIncludes>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                            </args>
                            <plugins>
                                <plugin>
                                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                                    <version>0.6.0</version>
                                </plugin>
                                <plugin>
                                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                                    <version>0.6.0</version>
                                </plugin>
                            </plugins>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Here is the catalog file:

```
PUBLIC "http://com.test.schema/common/Context" "maven:com.bar.foo:schema-a:jar::1.2!"
```

There is some configuration in the xjb file to make sure that XmlRootElement is written into some generated classes:

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
jxb:version="2.1" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
<jxb:globalBindings>
    <xjc:simple />
</jxb:globalBindings>   
<jxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="A.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='ADataType']">
        <jxb:class name="AData" />
        <annox:annotate>
            <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement"
                name="AData" />
        </annox:annotate>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Inspite of providing the episode to the xjc execution and the location of the schema for B.xsd in the catalog file, the classes for B.xsd is getting generated.

The issue is that the maven artifact referred to by the catalog file is not being picked up. I see the following error in the maven build logs:

```
Malformed URL on system identifier: maven:com.bar.foo:schema-b:jar::1.2!
PUBLIC: http://com.test.schema/common/Context
maven:com.bar.foo:schema-a:jar::1.2!
```

Can anyone help tell me why am I hitting this malformed URL error for the artifact that contains B.xsd? Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of the [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

First, you're probably mixing `A` and `B` here. You're saying `A` imports `B` but then you're using the `schema-a` artifact as episode. If `B` is imported, you should use `schema-b` as episode to not regenerate `B` stuff when compiling `A`.

But I think this is probably just a minor mistake in the question.

You have two aspects here - episodes and catalogs.

Episodes allow you to skip generation of classes you've generated somewhere else already. So if you use `schema-b` artifact when compiling `schema-a` then XJC should not generate classes for `schema-b`. You don't need catalogs for that, it's independent.

Sometimes XJC still generates few leftovers - even if you use an episode. I often get `ObjectFactory` and maybe some enums or top-level-elements generated. I believe this is an issue in XJC, there's nothing I can do in the [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin) about it.
So as a workaround I just use `maven-antrun-plugin` to delete unnecessary generated things.

If you get all of the `B` stuff generated then you should check if `schema-b` artifact really have the episode file generated. Check if you have `META-INF/sun-jaxb.episode` inside the JAR. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9770029/303810) for some trivia on the episode file.

So if you correctly configure the correct episode artifact you should not get `B` things generated, you don't need catalogs for this.

What you need the catalog for is to avoid downloading `http://com.test.schema/common/Context/B.xsd` when compiling. You can use catalogs to point to anothe location. I think your problem here is that you refer `http://com.test.schema/common/Context` to `maven:com.bar.foo:schema-a:jar::1.2!` which obviously does not point to the schema resource.

If you have an import like

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://com.test.schema/common/Context" schemaLocation="http://com.test.schema/common/Context/B.xsd"/>
```

Then you should probably rewrite it as follows:

```
PUBLIC "http://com.test.schema/common/Context" "maven:com.bar.foo:schema-b:jar::1.2!/common/Context/B.xsd"
```

Assuming `schema-b` artifact contains your schema under `/common/Context/B.xsd`. Note that it maps *namespace*, not *schema location*.

You can also use `REWRITE_SYSTEM` to rewrite schema location. For example:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://com.test.schema" "maven:com.bar.foo:schema-b:jar::1.2!"
```

If you have an URL like `http://com.test.schema/common/Context/B.xsd`, it will be rewritten to `maven:com.bar.foo:schema-b:jar::1.2!/common/Context/B.xsd`. This will point to the resource `/common/Context/B.xsd` inside your `schema-b` JAR.

Another hint - if you use `schema-b` as dependency in your project, you can omit the version.

Here's an example of catalog from a real world project:

https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/master/schemas/src/main/resources/ogc/catalog.cat

It contains rewrites like:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net" "maven:org.jvnet.ogc:ogc-schemas:jar::!/ogc"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, there was a typo in the description. I meant schema-b.

Comment: You are right. I checked the episode file and bindings for the class that I was trying to re-use were missing. I did understand what you explained about catalog. But the according to the 2nd link that I posted in my description which talks about episodes, I could gather that catalogs were needed. I quote the sentence from the blog -- "Note that JAXB still needs to access BOTH A and B schemas during the compilation. And you probably don't want to manually copy or duplicate schemas."

Comment: @ShrinidhiAchar Well, I am the author of that document (2nd link).  
Yes, XJC needs access to both schemas but no, you don't necessarily need episodes for that. But it's recommended so that you don't need to access external resources during the build.