# How to exclude generating of episode file in jaxb2-maven-plugin version 2.5.0?

Tags: maven, xjc, jaxb2-maven-plugin, jaxb-episode

I use the [xjc](https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.3.1/xjc-mojo.html) goal of the [jaxb2-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.3.1/index.html) to generate Java classes from a set of xsd files.

A minimal, complete and verifiable example would be a Maven project with the following pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-episode-test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</source>
          </sources>
          <generateEpisode>false</generateEpisode>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

And a file called [example.xsd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xml-tools/sample-xsd-file-simple-schema?view=vs-2019) (any valid xsd file will do) in the *src/main/resources/* folder:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/PurchaseOrderSchema.xsd"
           targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/PurchaseOrderSchema.xsd"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
 <xsd:element name="PurchaseOrder" type="tns:PurchaseOrderType"/>
 <xsd:complexType name="PurchaseOrderType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="ShipTo" type="tns:USAddress" maxOccurs="2"/>
   <xsd:element name="BillTo" type="tns:USAddress"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="OrderDate" type="xsd:date"/>
 </xsd:complexType>

 <xsd:complexType name="USAddress">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="name"   type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="city"   type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="state"  type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="zip"    type="xsd:integer"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:NMTOKEN" fixed="US"/>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

`<generateEpisode>false</generateEpisode>` makes sure that the code is generated **without** an [episode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756185/what-is-an-episode-file) file.

I need to upgrade the version of the plugin to [*2.5.0*](https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.5.0/index.html). In this version, [`generateEpisode`](https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.5.0/xjc-mojo.html#generateEpisode) has been deprecated:

> From plugin version 2.4, this parameter will not be used. Instead, episode files are generated by default with all JAXB operations.
>
> Starting with plugin version 2.4, use the parameter episodeFileName to provide a custom name of the generated episode File (or rely on the standard file name STANDARD_EPISODE_FILENAME).

Simply changing the `version` to *2.5.0* gives the following build-time error:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\path-to-the-project\target\generated-sources\jaxb\META-INF\JAXB\episode_xjc.xjb

By switching `generateEpisode` to `true` the build is successful, but the code is generated with an episode file, which I want to avoid. (As a side note, this proves that `generateEpisode` in fact is not ignored, despite what the documentation says).

How do I disable the generation of an episode file with version *2.5.0* of the plugin, if at all possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research, I have come to the conclusion that this functionality does not longer exist.

However, I have found two workaround ways of excluding the episode file:

**Using [JAXB2 Maven Plugin (maven-jaxb2-plugin)](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin) instead of jaxb2-maven-plugin**

JAXB2 Maven Plugin is a similar plugin which still supports generation without episode file:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.14.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>xjc</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
            <episode>false</episode> <!-- skips episode file generation -->
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

**Deleting the file with a separate plugin**

After the original plugin, the [Apache Maven AntRun plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) can be used to delete the file:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <target>
          <delete>
            <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb/META-INF/JAXB" includes="episode*.xjb" />
          </delete>
        </target>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This needs to be hooked to the `generate-sources` phase so it is executed directly after the code generation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use apache cxf instead, as cxf does not generate episode file.

https://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html