# JAXB2 source generation

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, jaxb, spring-ws

I have `User` entity with Hibernate and Validation annotations as below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "User", propOrder = {
        "id",
        "login"
})
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @XmlElement(required = true, type = Long.class, nillable = true)
    private Long id;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}$",
             message = "Login must contains from 3 to 20 latin characters or numbers!")
    @Column(name = "LOGIN", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String login;
}
```

When I write xsd schema with entity and `getUserRequest` / `getUserResponse`;
`maven-jaxb2-plugin` generate `GetUserRequest.java`, `GetUserResponse.java` and `User.java` into package along with my `User` class (*duplicate class if I try compile this*).

```
<xs:complexType name="User">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long" nillable="true"/>
        <xs:element name="login" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="getUserRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="userId" type="xs:long"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="getUserResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="user" type="tns:User"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I want to use my `User` class and not the generated one. (*if I remove generated User and start application all works fine*).

It's needed to my spring-ws ednpoint

```
@Endpoint
public class UserEndpoint {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @ResponsePayload
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = SOAP_NAMESPACE, localPart = "getUserRequest")
    public GetUserResponse getUser(@RequestPayload GetUserRequest request) {
        springapp.domain.User user =
                userService.getUser(request.getUserId());
        GetUserResponse response = new GetUserResponse();
        response.setUser(toSchemaType(user));
        return response;
    }
    private springapp.schema.User toSchemaType(springapp.domain.User user) {
        springapp.schema.User schemaUser = new springapp.schema.User();
        if (user.getId() != null) {
            schemaUser.setId(user.getId());
        }
        schemaUser.setLogin(user.getLogin());
        return schemaUser;
    }
}
```

Thanks to lexicore.
I have created `domain.xjb`:

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
               xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="users.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='User']">
            <jxb:class ref="springapp.domain.User"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

and added into `maven-jaxb2-plugin` configuration:

```
<bindingDirectory>src/main/resources</bindingDirectory>
<bindingIncludes>
    <include>domain.xjb</include>
</bindingIncludes>
```

And it works for me.

Comment: Why do you generate classes from your XSD if you don't need them?

Comment: @lexicore, I needed it for my UserEndpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jaxb:class/@ref` binnding to tell XJC you already have a `User` class. See this question:

> [JAXB: Prevent classes from being regenerated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841752/jaxb-prevent-classes-from-being-regenerated)

But I'd personally just write the two classes you need for the endpoint per hand and avoid the schema compilation altogether.

Comment: @ArthurGavlukovskii Feel free to accept the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

I actually created class `CoversionUtils`as a [Spring WS samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws-samples/blob/master/airline/server/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/samples/airline/schema/support/SchemaConversionUtils.java). I spent 2 days and not found another way.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @rchang Method `toSchemaType` in my `UserEndpoint` is a solution.