# JAXB class ref prevent enum generation

Tags: xsd, jaxb, wsdl, jax-ws, xsd2code

I've found this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841752/jaxb-prevent-classes-from-being-regenerated) already and was able to prevent the generation of classes, but enums are still generated.

I've tried to prevent it with custom binding:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='myEnum']">
      <jxb:class ref="com.myapp.enums.MyEnum" />
</jxb:bindings>
```

but it is not working for me.
Is there any possibility to prevent the generation of enums or maybe another customization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use following snippet

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='myEnum']">
      <jxb:typesafeEnumClass ref="com.myapp.enums.MyEnum"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```